# How to inject environment variables in Varnish configuration

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have 2 environments variables :

```
echo $FRONT1_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR # 172.17.1.80
echo $FRONT2_PORT_8081_TCP_ADDR # 172.17.1.77
```

I want to inject them in a my default.vcl like :

```
backend front1 {
    .host = $FRONT1_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR;
}
```

But I got an syntax error on the `$` char.

I've also tried with [user variables](https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmod/variable-support) but I can't define them outside `vcl_recv`.

How can I retrieve my 2 values in the VCL ?

Comment: Have someone tried https://github.com/carlosabalde/libvmod-cfg ? It helps to access ENV variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to parse my vcl

```
backend front1 {
    .host = ${FRONT1_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR};
}
```

With a script:

```
envs=`printenv`

for env in $envs
do
    IFS== read name value <<< "$env"

    sed -i "s|\${${name}}|${value}|g" /etc/varnish/default.vcl
done
```

Answer (score 7):

Now you can use the VMOD Varnish Standard Module (std) to get environment variables in the VCL, for example:

```
set req.backend_hint = app.backend(std.getenv("VARNISH_BACKEND_HOSTNAME"));
```

See documentation: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vmod_std.html#std-getenv

Comment: Is it not just for enterprise version?

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** it doesn't work for backend configuration, but could work elsewhere. Apparently backends are expecting constant strings and if you try, you'll get `Expected CSTR got 'std.fileread'`.

You can use the [`fileread` function of the `std` module](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/vmod_std.generated.html#func-fileread), and create a file for each of your environment variables.

before running varnishd, you can run:

```
mkdir -p /env; \
env | while read envline; do \
    k=${envline%%=*}; \
    v=${envline#*=}; \
    echo -n "$v" >"/env/$k"; \
done
```

And then, within your varnish configuration:

```
import std;

...

backend front1 {
    .host = std.fileread("/env/FRONT1_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR");
    .port = std.fileread("/env/FRONT1_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT");
}
```

I haven't tested it yet. Also, I don't know if giving a string to the port configuration of the backend would work. In that case, converting to an integer should work:

```
.port = std.integer(std.fileread("/env/FRONT1_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT"), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use use echo to eval strings.

Usually you can do something like:

```
VAR=test # Define variables

echo "my $VAR string" # Eval string
```

But, If you have the text in a file, you can use "eval" to have the same behaviour:

```
VAR=test # Define variables

eval echo $(cat file.vcl) # Eval string from the given file
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for `envsubst`.

Just use standard env var syntax in your config $MY_VAR and ...

```
envsubst < myconfig.tmpl > myconfig.vcl
```

You can install with `apt get install gettext` in Ubuntu.