# Cannot use std vmod in varnish 6.5.1

Tags: docker, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am using the official `varnish:6.5.1` docker image and have this vcl:

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;

backend default {
    .host = std.getenv("PROXY_HOST");
    .port = std.getenv("PROXY_PORT");
}
.....
```

When I try to run the image (with docker-compose) it instantly fails with this error:

```
varnish_1  | Could not delete 'vcl_boot.1612728251.581028/vgc.sym': No such file or directory
varnish_1  | Error:
varnish_1  | Message from VCC-compiler:
varnish_1  | Expected CSTR got 'std'
varnish_1  | (program line 369), at
varnish_1  | ('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 13 Pos 17)
varnish_1  |         .host = std.getenv("PROXY_HOST");
```

How is this failing? I would understand not being able to connect to the backend but the VCL parse should be fine, the documentation on the std VMOD is very simple for `getenv`.

What am I missing here?

EDIT

```
backend default {
    .host = "${PROXY_HOST}";
    .port = "${PROXY_PORT}";
}
```

in combination with

```
#!/bin/bash
envs=`printenv`

for env in $envs
do
    IFS== read name value <<< "$env"

    sed -i "s|\${${name}}|${value}|g" /etc/varnish/default.vcl
done

varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

works as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056450/how-to-inject-environment-variables-in-varnish-configuration) post but that seems hardly optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Varnish Cache only supports static backends

Varnish Cache, the open source version of Varnish doesn't support dynamic backends.

When the VCL file is loaded and compiled, the `.host` and `.port` values need to be strings, not expressions.

The error message also indicates this:

```
Expected CSTR got 'std'
```

The compiler says it expects a C-string, which means something that starts with a quote, but instead it found `std`.

### Dynamic backend support in Varnish Enterprise

[Varnish Enterprise](https://www.varnish-software.com/solutions/varnish-enterprise/), the commercial version of Varnish, does support dynamic backends.
See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/goto/ for more information.

**Disclaimer:** although *Varnish Enterprise* is the commercial version of *Varnish Cache*, you can still use it without upfront license payments if you use it on AWS, Azure or GCP.

- [Varnish Enterprise on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Varnish-Software-Inc-Varnish-Enterprise-6-Ubuntu/prodview-atq2qasjkejio)
- [Varnish Enterprise on Azure](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/varnish.varnish-enterprise)
- [Varnish Enterprise on GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/varnish-public/varnish-enterprise-6-payg-ubuntu)